# UnboundLocalError local variable 'context' referenced before assignment Django

Tags: python, django

I get the error below immediately after i add a new root url inside the root urls.py.

When i remove the dashboard view, url and i try to load index view, it renders successfully. What am i doing wrong or what can i do to resolve the issue.

Error message

```
UnboundLocalError at /blogapp/
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogapp/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment
```

My views

```
from multiprocessing import context
import re
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .odd_finder_func import *


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        odd1 = float(request.POST.get('odd1'))
        odd2 = float(request.POST.get('odd2'))
        odd3 = float(request.POST.get('odd3'))

        func_def = odd_finder_true(odd1, odd2, odd3)

        context = {
            'Juice': func_def['Juice'],
            'TotalImpliedProbability': func_def['TotalImpliedProbability'],
            'HomeOdd': func_def['HomeOdd'],
            'DrawOdd': func_def['DrawOdd'],
            'AwayOdd': func_def['AwayOdd'],
            'Home_True_Odd': func_def['Home_True_Odd'],
            'Draw_True_Odd': func_def['Draw_True_Odd'],
            'Away_True_Odd': func_def['Away_True_Odd'],
            'True_Probability': func_def['True_Probability']
            }

        context = context

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

blogapp urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

myblog urls.py the root file.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from blogapp import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path('blogapp/', include('blogapp.urls')),
]
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- Content here -->

        
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Odd1" class="form-label">Home Odd</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="odd1" id="odd1" min="0" value=" " step=".01" required='required'>
          </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="Odd2" class="form-label">Draw Odd</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="odd2" id="odd2" min="0" value=" " step=".01" required='required'>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="Odd3" class="form-label">Away Odd</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="odd3" id="odd3" min="0" value=" " step=".01" required='required'>
          </div>
       
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">
      </form>

      </div>
       

      <div class="container">
        <p>Total Implied probability percentage: {{TotalImpliedProbability}}</p>
        <p>Bookie juice is: {{Juice}}</p>
        <p>Home Odd: {{HomeOdd}}</p>
        <p>Draw Odd: {{DrawOdd}}</p>
        <p>Away Odd: {{AwayOdd}}</p>
        <p>Home True Odd: {{Home_True_Odd}}</p>
        <p>Draw True Odd: {{Draw_True_Odd}}</p>
        <p>Away True Odd: {{Away_True_Odd}}</p>
        <p>True Probability is: {{True_Probability}}</p>
       
      </div>

      



    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    
    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is an attachment of the django app files is set up.

[image]

Comment: You only set a value for `context` inside the `request.method == 'POST'` block - which means that if you do a GET request, the `context` variable is never defined, and hence an error when you try to use that variable in `render()`. You need to define a default context which is used for GET.

Comment: Thank you for response, @solarissmoke How can i implement that in my views.py.

Comment: I feel like I have given enough of a clue for you to try and fix this yourself - I'm not going to just give you code, because I think it's more helpful for you to understand the *cause* of the issue and to figure out how to apply that understanding in your code.

Comment: I appreciate the support sir, I'm new to django and python, was just surprised it worked first time, however when i remove the the dashboard url in root urls, the error will disappear but now that means my app will only have one url and view. I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define context when `if request.method == "GET"`

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        odd1 = float(request.POST.get("odd1"))
        odd2 = float(request.POST.get("odd2"))
        odd3 = float(request.POST.get("odd3"))

        func_def = odd_finder_true(odd1, odd2, odd3)

        context = {
            "Juice": func_def["Juice"],
            "TotalImpliedProbability": func_def["TotalImpliedProbability"],
            "HomeOdd": func_def["HomeOdd"],
            "DrawOdd": func_def["DrawOdd"],
            "AwayOdd": func_def["AwayOdd"],
            "Home_True_Odd": func_def["Home_True_Odd"],
            "Draw_True_Odd": func_def["Draw_True_Odd"],
            "Away_True_Odd": func_def["Away_True_Odd"],
            "True_Probability": func_def["True_Probability"],
        }

        context = context

        # INDENT THIS
        return render(request, "index.html", context)
    else:
        # WHAT IS THE CONTEXT WHEN request.method == "GET" ?
        return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the variable `context` you created has the same name as the `context` you imported from multiprocessing at the top of the file. Changing the variable name should fix the problem.

```
from multiprocessing import context
import re
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .odd_finder_func import *


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        odd1 = float(request.POST.get('odd1'))
        odd2 = float(request.POST.get('odd2'))
        odd3 = float(request.POST.get('odd3'))

        func_def = odd_finder_true(odd1, odd2, odd3)

        response_context = {
            'Juice': func_def['Juice'],
            'TotalImpliedProbability': func_def['TotalImpliedProbability'],
            'HomeOdd': func_def['HomeOdd'],
            'DrawOdd': func_def['DrawOdd'],
            'AwayOdd': func_def['AwayOdd'],
            'Home_True_Odd': func_def['Home_True_Odd'],
            'Draw_True_Odd': func_def['Draw_True_Odd'],
            'Away_True_Odd': func_def['Away_True_Odd'],
            'True_Probability': func_def['True_Probability']
            }

    return render(request, 'index.html', response_context)
```

Comment: Have changed and still i'm getting the same error for new `response_context`

Comment: @solarissmoke has a clue on what the issue is, the problem is i dont know how to implement or do another get request in the same view to make the error disappear when i'm doing get request. I'm new to django.